# Изменить фон при скролле вниз на 100vh

Tags: jquery, css

Есть фиксированный хедер, в нём есть кнопка (#button), фон кнопки изначально прозрачен. Но при прокрутке страницы вниз на 100vh фон кнопки должен менять свой цвет. Как это можно сделать на jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const $window = $(window);

$window.on('scroll', onScroll);

function onScroll() {
  if($window.scrollTop() >= $window.height()) {
    // Тут задаешь стили кнопке
  } else {
    // тут отменяешь
  }
}
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Работает!Спасибо